# General question regarding installed modules and performance

Tags: performance, addons

I probably have a few modules installed on some of my sites that aren't being used. Simple question: will uninstalling them improve general memory usage and performance?

One module in particular that definitely isn't being used is the Comments module.

Cheers

Jim

Comment: Yes, unused module will increase the performance. While EE sends any request, all the installed modules are initialized to fetch their details into system.

Comment: As I suspected Bhashkar. Interested to find out if EE will even run without the Comments module though. Guess there's only one way to find out!

Comment: Yes, you can un-install the Comments module if you are not using it. EE will run properly without Comments module.

Comment: There's several I uninstall regularly - comments, blacklist, emoticons, and even email (since I tend to use third party modules for email anyway) and no ill effects that I've discovered from taking that approach.  Same goes for fieldtypes. If you know you don't need it, you can certainly take it out.

Comment: As a rule I uninstall every module/fieldtype/accessory I'm not using. Trim it down I say :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will un-installing modules increase performance? yes.  Will it increase *noticeable* performance? Almost certainly not.  The overhead of unused modules is tiny compared to what else EE loads:

Having a quick look with debugging on shows one SQL query to retrive available modules.

```
SELECT `module_version`, `module_name`
FROM (`exp_modules`)
```

Looking at later queries, only modules that are actually used show any other SQL queries.

Given that exp_modules is a pretty small table (10 or so entries) in comparison to a channel table (10K+), it's one of the cheapest queries performed.  Without digging into the source and seeing what file systems operations are performed I can't say for sure, but as a general rule it's always the database queries that hurt performance rather than file loads.

So perhaps another question is; are there any other reasons you should uninstall unused modules? YES!  Every module increases your attack surface size, if you have un-installed a module, logically a vulnerability in that module can not be used against you.  This should be part of your vertical system hardening from the operating system->web server->PHP->EE where you disable unused components from every part of your system.  See the [canonical serverfault question for more](https://serverfault.com/questions/212269/tips-for-securing-a-lamp-server) tips.

Answer (score 0):

Also better saving pages just into ee and not as files will bring you huge improvements on the performance side !